# How to Disconnect Socket in C#, Boolean variable ReuseSocket. What is the purpose

Tags: c#, sockets, network-programming

What is the purpose of using ReuseSocket to true. I dont know what it do if i set this property to true. What happens if i set ReuseSocket to true or flase.
I am trying to create a socket but it is giving me error again nd again.

Error

```
A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied: Stack:    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Send(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Send(Byte[] buffer)
   at Serverdll.ServerApp.StopReceiveServer() : Function Name : Int32 Send(Byte[], Int32, Int32, System.Net.Sockets.SocketFlags)


Description :Address Already In Use., Error Code: 10048, Message On Start: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally only one socket for a particular protocol is allowed to be bound to a given address at once. So you can have only one UDP socket bound to a particular IP address and port.

If you need to have multiple sockets bound to the same combination of protocol/ip address/port then you should set the `ReuseAddress` socket option to true on Socket you create before you call `Bind()` (or any method which implicitly binds the Socket).

Otherwise, you should ensure that the one socket is closed using one of the `Close()` methods before creating another.

Answer (score 0):

When the connection is closed there is still a long waiting period as defined by the [TCP specifications](http://kb.iu.edu/data/ajmi.html). This option allows you to minimize the waiting time for closing a connection